# SubQuery não interpretada / falhando

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Utilizando Sub-Query, faça uma query que retorne os materiais ativos, com a Descrição, Lote, Cod de Barras e Validade somente da Dt Validade menor de cada Material.

**Meu código até o momento:**

```
select R.COD_MATERIAL, 
   M.DESCRICAO, 
   (select L.LOTE from TR_LOTE L 
           where L.DT_VALIDADE = (select min(L.DT_VALIDADE) from TR_LOTE L 
                                        where L.LOTE = (select L.LOTE from TR_LOTE L))) as LOTE,
   (select R.COD_BARRA from TR_REL_MATERIAL_LOTE R 
           where R.LOTE = NULL) as COD_BARRAS,
   min(L.DT_VALIDADE) 

   from TR_REL_MATERIAL_LOTE R

   inner join TR_MATERIAL M on R.COD_MATERIAL = M.COD_MATERIAL 
   inner join TR_LOTE L on R.LOTE = L.LOTE

   group by R.COD_MATERIAL, M.DESCRICAO

   order by R.COD_MATERIAL
```

Não estou conseguindo retornar o esperado, não sei se foi por falta de interpretação ou não faço idéia de como fazer isso.

Mas preciso **retornar especificamente o Lote de cada Material** em sua respectiva data de validade (*menor data da validade*) além de seu código de barras, seguindo o exemplo do retorno dessa query abaixo:

```
select R.COD_MATERIAL, 
   M.DESCRICAO, 
   min(L.DT_VALIDADE) 

   from TR_REL_MATERIAL_LOTE R

   inner join TR_MATERIAL M on R.COD_MATERIAL = M.COD_MATERIAL 
   inner join TR_LOTE L on R.LOTE = L.LOTE

   group by R.COD_MATERIAL, M.DESCRICAO

   order by R.COD_MATERIAL
```

A imagem em anexo mostra como são estruturadas as tabelas.
Obrigado a quem puder ajudar!

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59GcW.png)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Olá

A subquery no SELECT só pode/deve retornar 1 registro, então você deve sempre colocar "TOP 1" nela, e uma cláusula "ORDER BY" para dizer qual seu critério do que constitui um primeiro registro.

O "inner join TR_LOTE" obviamente também não é mais necessário, e poderia gerar um produto cartesiano, já que você está buscando os dados do lote unica e exclusivamente nas subqueries.

O "group by R.COD_MATERIAL, M.DESCRICAO" também não é mais necessário, visto que nosso SELECT principal não contém mais funções agregadoras.

Então ficaria:

```
select
  R.COD_MATERIAL, 
  M.DESCRICAO, 
  (select top 1 L.LOTE from TR_LOTE L where L.LOTE = R.LOTE order by L.DT_VALIDADE) as LOTE,
  (select top 1 L.DT_VALIDADE from TR_LOTE L
   where L.LOTE = R.LOTE order by L.DT_VALIDADE) as DT_VALIDADE,
  (select top 1 R.COD_BARRA from TR_LOTE L
   inner join TR_REL_MATERIAL_LOTE R on R.LOTE = L.LOTE
   order by L.DT_VALIDADE) as COD_BARRA

from TR_REL_MATERIAL_LOTE R
inner join TR_MATERIAL M on R.COD_MATERIAL = M.COD_MATERIAL 
order by R.COD_MATERIAL
```

Esta query porém não ficou elegante, pois em casa subquery buscamos novamente a mesma consulta em TR_LOTE, sempre ordenada por DT_VALIDADE, somente para em cada caso retornar uma coluna diferente. Além disso, na terceira subquery, eu consulto novamente TR_REL_MATERIAL_LOTE, numa nova instância, que é a mesma tabela da minha query principal.

Não precisamos usar subqueries somente na cláusula SELECT. Há vários outros pontos onde podemos utilizá-las, que podem dar soluções melhores.

Este problema se encaixa num padrão que frequentemente acontece, em que temos que encontrar o campo de menor valor (no caso, DT_VALIDADE) e, a partir daí, encontrar vários outros campos correlatos a este. Não há uma forma trivial de trazer tudo de uma vez só. Este tipo de padrão requer a quebra de query em duas etapas.

Uma solução melhor seria:

```
select
  R.COD_MATERIAL, 
  M.DESCRICAO, 
  R.LOTE,
  MenorDataMaterial.DT_VALIDADE,
  R.COD_BARRA
from (
  select RX.COD_MATERIAL, MIN(L.DT_VALIDADE) [DT_VALIDADE]
  from TR_REL_MATERIAL RX
  inner join TR_LOTE L on L.LOTE = RX.LOTE
  group by RX.COD_MATERIAL
) MenorDataMaterial
inner join TR_REL_MATERIAL_LOTE R on R.COD_MATERIAL = MenorDataMaterial.COD_MATERIAL
inner join TR_MATERIAL M on R.COD_MATERIAL = M.COD_MATERIAL 
order by R.COD_MATERIAL
```

Ficou bem mais simples, não? Ainda há outras soluções possíveis.